# How to filter by message content in LOGalyze?

Tags: tomcat, logalyze

How can filter by keyword contened in message body. (LOGalyse is based on tomcat engine)

I try syntax `message:"respawning"` but doesn't work

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post. But posting the answer as I was able to figure out wild card search.

LOGlyze supports wild card search.

In the search tab go to query textbox and type

message:*xxxxx*

Of course replace xxxxx with the text that you want to do he wildcard search :). If you want wildcard on the left or right use the asterix accordingly

Answer (score 0):

"message" is the default field for searching, so you do not need to specify the field name in this case. Use

```
severity:warn AND respawning
```

in this case.